# How can I call a template function in another template function

Tags: c++, c++14

I tried to write a generic print function in C++14. But template `printItem` function can not instantiate.

```
template <class T>
void printItem(T t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void printVector(T t)
{
    for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), printItem);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vs = {"word1", "word2"};

    printVector(vs);
}
```

This code causes a compiler error:

```
no matching function for call to 
'for_each(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Comment: Once you solve the "<unresolved overloaded function type>" issue, you still have another problem. `T` in `printItem` is `std::string`, so `*t` will not compile since `std::string` does not have an `operator*` implemented. Use `<< t` instead of `<< *t`.

Comment: actually star operator was a typo, I fixed after post. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printItem` is a function template, and it cannot deduce the argument type, so you need to specify that, like this:

```
for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), printItem<typename T::value_type>);
```

Additionally, there appears to be a typo in `printItem`. You don't need to dereference `t` at all.

If you are not using this function anywhere else, then you can define it inline using a lambda, like this:

```
for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), [](auto s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; });
```

Note that the lambda `operator()` is also templated in this case, however the type can be deduced, so it's fine.

Also, `std::for_each` is often a code smell, in my opinion. It can be replaced by the much more readable:

```
for (auto const &s : t)
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Comment: `for (const auto& s : t) std::cout << s;` ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the compiler to know which `printItem` specialisation you wanted, with the information available to it according to the standard at that point.

So, this syntax is not available here.

This is what you need:

```
for_each(t.begin(), t.end(), printItem<typename T::value_type>);
```

Being able to do this kind of thing is exactly why containers are required to define type aliases like `value_type`; you end up needing them all over the place.

A limitation in the language? Perhaps. But it does help avoid corner cases.

Having to use `typename` here certainly is [an annoyance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/4386278), though.

---

Your code, to be honest, would be a lot easier and clearer if you just used a loop:

```
for (const auto& item : t)
   printItem(item);
```

In the time of ranged-for and all that lovely stuff, `for_each` is not all that useful for common cases any more.

---

Also, take the arguments by reference-to-`const`, and remove the erroneous dereference. I'll also remove the repeated `std::endl`, which is performing stream flushing you don't need.

```
template <class T>
void printItem(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

template <class T>
void printVector(const T& t)
{
    for (const auto& item : t)
       printItem(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vs = {"word1", "word2"};
    printVector(vs);
}
```

Finally, it's a good idea to let functions like `printItem` take a reference to the stream you want to use, so that you could pick (say) a `std::stringstream` rather than *only* `std::cout`.